# When are the best times to prune or trim leylandii?

Tags: hedge, leylandii

We have a row of quite mature leylandii trees as a privacy screen which we wish to have shortened and trimmed, to turn into more of a hedge. Part of it was already done this summer but when are the good and bad times to do this?

I had theorised spring so it has the whole year to grow back?

Comment: The best *way* to prune them is cut them down to ground level with a chainsaw, then use a flame thrower on the roots, IMHO. But seriously, it doesn't really matter - any time of year is OK. Just beware than if you cut off *half* a branch, the remaining half will probably die back and leave either brown dead foliage, or a hole in the screen.

Comment: I thought as long as you didn't cut back to the brown wood, it would be OK? I'm not sure how cutting half the branch is different to trimming a hedge, could you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

The recommended time for cutting back mature leylandii hedges in the UK is two or three cuts between April and August, so its a little late now, though you could risk taking some off if you're desperate. More information here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=596